# ajax-jquery как работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
```

Что находится в data? Т.е. что это вообще такое, я привык видеть примерно следующее `parametr1=123&parametr2=123`, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data - данные, которые будут отправлены на сервер. Они могут быть трёх видов: Строка, Массив, Простой Объект.

$("...") - это функция Jquery, она возвращает в данном случае Объект представляющий список элементов на странице. Затем он преобразуется согласно формату: {fName1:value1, fName2:value2, ...}.

Comment: А как обработать эти данные, они же по post передаются? 
И как он преобразуется в формат `{fName1:value1, fName2:value2, ...}`, там же имен нет, а в обработчике берется значение $_POST['quantity'] например. 
 
P.S. Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, если что.

Comment: Метод передачи post определяется в свойстве type, в вашем примере это  type: 'post'. Имена это значение атрибута name в полях формы. Посмотреть что передается можно, например, в браузере Chrome открыв Developer Tools (F12), вкладка Networks - фильтр XHR, вызываем событие, выбираем его и смотрим в headers секцию Form Data

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` объект типа `{val1: 1, val2: 2}`. Это данные которые ты будешь передавать на сервер.

Так же можно передать любую строку. В частности пример перевода `JSON` объекта в строку `JSON.stringify(Object);`